# flex:how to get input values on creation complete

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have a datagrid,2 textboxes & a button .In the third textbox i want to display the total of one of the column in datagrid. The data in grid is populated on button click, depending upon the values in textbox. but until I  get values on creation complete,I am not getting the total.If i do calculateTotal() on button click M not gettting total.what can i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex is an event driven framework. Use events by the controls and the IList used as data provider to determine the state of te ui and the data itself. So you can easily get notifications when new data is available, when data changed etc.